# JQ 'select' or 'if'?

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "StatusInfos": null,
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": null,
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "test1"
}
{
  "StatusInfos": null,
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": null,
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "test2"
}
{
  "StatusInfos": [
    {
      "Status": "replicating",
      "StatusType": "read replication",
      "Normal": true
    }
  ],
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": "test1",
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "read-rep-test1"
}
{
  "StatusInfos": [
    {
      "Status": "replicating",
      "StatusType": "read replication",
      "Normal": true
    }
  ],
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": "test2",
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "read-rep-test2"
}
```

I'm trying to produce:

```
{
  "StatusInfos": null,
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": null,
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "test1"
}
{
  "StatusInfos": null,
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": null,
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "test2"
}
{
  "RepStatus": "replicating",
  "RepStatusType": "read replication",
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": "test1",
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "read-rep-test1"
}
{
  "RepStatus": "replicating",
  "RepStatusType": "read replication",
  "ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier": "test2",
  "DBInstanceIdentifier": "read-rep-test2"
}
```

I have tried dozens of variations of 'select' and 'if', most of which simply spit out errors.  My most recent attempt (I'm limited to jq 1.3 if that is important) produces neither errors nor output:

```
   cat json_file |
      jq -r '{ DBInstanceIdentifier,
               ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier
             } +
             ( select( .StatusType == "read replication" ) |
              .StatusInfos[] | { RepStatusType: .StatusType, RepStatus: .Status }
             )'
```

JQ is absolutely baffling to me.  I have referenced the manuals many times, but they give examples, not principles.  So in addition to how to solve my immediate problem, if you can recommend how I might go about actually understanding JQ, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` processing all entities but leaving the ones with `StatusInfos: null` intact would do as in:

```
jq -r 'if .StatusInfos != null then {
    RepStatus: .StatusInfos[0].Status,
    RepStatusType: .StatusInfos[0].StatusType,
    ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier,
    DBInstanceIdentifier } else . end'
```

or, when required to deal with multiple StatusInfo's:

```
jq -r 'if .StatusInfos != null then 
        .StatusInfos[] as $info | {
             RepStatus: $info.Status,
             RepStatusType: $info.StatusType,
             ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier,
             DBInstanceIdentifier }
    else . end'
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Accepted.

Hmmmmmm.............but this assumes that the status I want is always the first [0] element of the StatusInfos array, right?  What if it isn't?

Comment: I think this variation is is what I'm looking for............

`
    cat json_file | jq -r 'if .StatusInfos != null then
       select( .StatusInfos[].StatusType == "read replication") |
       {
          RepStatus: .StatusInfos[].Status,
          RepStatusType: .StatusInfos[].StatusType,
          ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier,
          DBInstanceIdentifier
       }
       else . end'
`

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry, it is not completely obvious from the example what the possible input permutations are and then what the desired outcome must be for each case

Comment: I've added a variant/example that deals with multiple status info's that may help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
reduce ((.StatusInfos//[])[] | select(.StatusType == "read replication")) as $info
    ({ ReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier, DBInstanceIdentifier };
    .RepStatus = $info.Status | .RepStatusType = $info.StatusType)
```

If you had access to a more recent version of jq, you could utilize the error ignoring filters to change `(.StatusInfos//[])[]` to `.StatusInfos?[]?`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation which replaces `StatusInfos` with attributes from its last array element if possible.

```
if .StatusInfos == null
then .
else .RepStatus     = .StatusInfos[-1].Status
   | .RepStatusType = .StatusInfos[-1].StatusType
   | del(.StatusInfos)
end
```